# Database Design of static data and progress data

Tags: database

if I have some data should be static to be the source

Table Person A (static)
Happiness 0

And I need a table for store the user playing progress

Table User_1_Person_A
Happiness 5

How can I design the database smarty?
My only idea is

Table Person_A
Happiness 5 User_id 1

But two tables columns will be the same. Is it a bad design? Thanks

Comment: From your description I undertand nothing. Could you describe the problem using few sentences without this pseudo tables?

Comment: I have to design a database include two parts.One is store the static data for initialize state. Another part for store the progress. For example, player 1 's skill level is 0 at the beginning (static). After some decision, player 1 's skill level is 1(progress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a guess at what you're asking.

### Progress

If you want to keep track of progress, you'll need a table with a time stamp.

Here's how I'd define your tables.

```
Person
------
Person ID
Person User ID
Person Name
...
```

Person ID is the primary (clustering) key of the Person table.  It is an auto-incrementing integer or long.

```
Skill
-----
Skill ID
Skill Name
```

Skill ID is the primary (clustering) key of the Skill table.  It is an auto-incrementing integer or long.

```
Progress
--------
Progress ID
Person ID
Skill ID
Progress Timestamp
Progress Level
```

Progress ID is the primary (clustering) key of the Progress table.  It is an auto-incrementing integer or long.

You create another unique index on (Person ID, Skill ID, Progress Timestamp DESCENDING).  This allows you to select the most recent (highest) skill level for any skill.

### Initial

You'll need one more table to set the initial progress level for any skill.

```
Initial
-------
Initial ID
Skill ID
Initial Level
```

Initial ID is the primary (clustering) key of the Initial table.  It is an auto-incrementing integer or long.

### Summary

This process of organizing data elements into database tables is called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the poor explanation